# Why is ScrollView hiding its children when I examine it using Enzyme in Jest?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme, expo

I'm have a React Native project and am using Jest + Enzyme for a test environment.

Whenever I try to mount something with a ScrollView component, I can't seem to see below it in the component tree.

Here is my test:

```
describe('Example test', () => {
  it('should find text', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<View><Text>lorem ipsum dolor sit</Text></View>);
    expect(wrapper.find('Text').length).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('should find text in ScrollView', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ScrollView><Text>lorem ipsum dolor sit</Text></ScrollView>);
    expect(wrapper.find('Text').length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

The first test works fine, when I wrap it in a `View`.  It is able to see the `Text` just fine.

the second test fails because it is not seeing any `Text` components under the `ScrollView`.

Any ideas why?

I have a full test example set up here:
https://github.com/lehresman/react-native-jest-scrollview-failure

Just follow the instructions in the README to get it going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to mock it, check this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13034).

I tried with this code and it works.

```
jest.mock("ScrollView", () => {
   const RealComponent = require.requireActual("ScrollView");
   const React = require("React");
   class ScrollView extends React.Component {
   scrollTo() {}

   render() {
      return React.createElement("ScrollView", this.props, 
   this.props.children);
   }
  }
  ScrollView.propTypes = RealComponent.propTypes;
  return ScrollView;
});
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I do already have a workaround similar to this.  But it seems like it shouldn't be necessary, right?  Any idea what's going on to make this necessary?

Comment: Apparently simulating `ScrollView` is a little different than other react-native components, That also happen with `ListView` I believe, in the issue I mentioned, You may notice the PR for `SrollViewMock` which is the component that gets called when we do jest.mock("ScrollView", ... ), as far as I know I don't think there is another solution besides this one.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation.  We are going with this route.